# Anyone know of open source code for doing a preview of an image

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

Does anyone know of any open source code for doing a preview of an image? I have an image stored in the Documents folder of my application and would like to show a preview of the image in a modal popup by passing in a URL to the local file. I am looking for some open source code either in MonoTouch or Objective C that provides a preview that has zooming and panning functionality. I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel if there is already open source code that does this... what can I say, I am inherently lazy... hehe ;)

My preference goes to C# code, as my application is coded in C#, but if there is a good Objective C solution for this then I will port it to MonoTouch and make my source available here.

Comment: @Black Frog You are right. I read it as wanting to use it straight out of the box. Obviously missed the second para.

Comment: @Deepak I don't know what Black Frog wrote because I don't see the comment now. But, no, not wanting something straight out of the box, just wanting ideas so that I don't do unnecessary work... and because my boss wants this yesterday! haha The "inherently lazy" was a joke, but I think I'm drawing a lot of attention for saying that... cos i see comments being made and then deleted.

Comment: No. I had suggested using QLPreviewController if you wanted something out of the box and later was corrected by @Black Frog about your intentions. I had added it as an answer but withdrew after I realized it was not relevant.

Comment: @Deepak Ah, ok. I saw your answer about QLPreviewController and was going to make a comment on there that I never even knew that existed in iOS SDK. I am definitely going to take a look at that. Thanks for posting about QLPreviewController... I learnt something new today! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout TTPhotoViewController:
http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/

Comment: Thanks, Anne. From the description of TTPhotoViewController I read there, this seems perfect... I have downloaded it and will try using it. :) Thanks.

Comment: I found a lightweight photo viewer controller called MTGalleryViewController and used btouch to bring this into MonoTouch. I found the source code for this over here: https://github.com/mtuzzolo/MTGallery. I found this code simpler and easier to import into MonoTouch. But I am going to give you the credit for this answer. Thanks for your answer, Anne.