# Static library not working after update of Monotouch/Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, static-linking

About two years ago I built an image viewer into my Monotouch application. See [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191272/anyone-know-of-open-source-code-for-doing-a-preview-of-an-image/6191331#comment26340176_6191331) from way back when I was looking for an image viewer for monotouch. I used the source of [MTGallery](https://github.com/tuzzolo/MTGallery) and used *btouch* to bring this into my Monotouch application. This worked perfectly and has been working perfectly for the last two years. But at some point in the last six months one of the updates that I did to *Monodevelop* has broken this functionality. Now the viewer is not showing the image, it is just showing a blank screen. The source for this hasn't changed, in fact it I still have the compiled library that was compiled two years ago.

I know that at the end of last year, I could compile my Monotouch application and the image viewer would work correctly. I have a backup of the application source from December 2012. If I deploy the version that was compiled then to my iPad it works correctly. But if I recompile the same source now without making *any* changes to the source or the settings in Monodevelop, it doesn't work.

So, this is what I have tried: Updated *Monodevelop* (I had to upgrade my Mac OS to *Mountain Lion* to be able to do this). Installed *Xamarin Studio* and got a new license for this development environment. The image viewer does not work when compiled in either *Monodevelop* or *Xamarin Studio*. I have tried recompiling the Objective-C library. I tried using *btouch* again to recreate the C# files for inclusion in my project.

Nothing I have tried so far has helped. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue and what I could try changing to get this working.

UPDATE:

I am now a step further; I have determined that the static library is in fact being called and if I rotate my iPad the image is then showing in the viewer, but is not showing before a rotation takes place. From looking at the Objective-C code it appears that the image was initially being loaded by the *scrollViewDidEndDecelerating* delegate method of the UIScrollView. It seems that this is now not firing when the image viewer loads, whereas previously it was firing.

Answer (score 2):

If it did work and suddenly doesn't without any change from you, it's probably a bug in Xamarin.iOS/Studio. The best way to get this fixed is to create a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) and attach your project so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, Rolf. I am going to make a small sample application using the library to test it. Just to confirm that the error does lie with the statically linked image viewer and not else where. When I have confirmed that I will post the sample app to the url you mentioned. Thanks for the help.